# How to change pdf filenames in a directory from excel data?

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, filenames

I have an excel file with a column named old_name. Which is a column of a list of old filenames that need to be changed. Then in the next column I have new_name. I want to change all pdfs in a directory from old name to the new name.
Like this:

| Old_name | New_name |
| --- | --- |
| Nike | Adidas |
| Puma | Gucci |

The code I've tried is:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

directory = r"C:\x\x\x\PDF"
df = pd.read_excel("New_name.xlsx")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    old_name = row["Old_name"]
    new_name = row["New_name"]
    old_path = os.path.join(directory, old_name)
    new_path = os.path.join(directory, new_name)

    if os.path.exists(old_path) and old_name.endswith(".pdf"):
        os.rename(old_path, new_path)
        print(f"Renamed {old_path} to {new_path}")
```

The problem is that I get a error of FileNotFoundError. Using this code, it seems like it's looking for the new_name data in the directory, they are not there (they are in the excel) so then it says error due to not finding in the directory.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong formating of the code. Still figuring out how to use the toolbar to make it look correct.

Comment: Copy the code in the editor of this site, select it (all at once) and click `{}` button.

Comment: Having the data in Excel makes you want to gnaw off your own leg. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.read_excel("New_name.xlsx") 
directory = r"C:/x/x/x/PDF/"
replace_dict = dict(zip(df["Old_name"].unique(), df["New_name"].unique()))

pdf_files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if ".pdf" in f]

for old, new in replace_dict.items():
    if f"{old}.pdf" in pdf_files:
        os.rename(f"{directory}/{old}.pdf", f"{directory}/{new}.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't trigger the `FileNotFoundError` with your code. Although this one does not rename the files, no error is thrown since the `if` is never satisfied. Anyways, to fix your code, you need to add the `.pdf` extension to the filenames from your *spreadsheet/df* :

```
directory = "C:/x/x/x/PDF"
df = pd.read_excel("New_name.xlsx")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    old_name = f'{row["Old_name"]}.pdf' # <- updated
    new_name = f'{row["New_name"]}.pdf' # <- updated
    old_path = os.path.join(directory, old_name)
    new_path = os.path.join(directory, new_name)
        
    if os.path.exists(old_path): # <- updated
        os.rename(old_path, new_path)
        print(f"Renamed {old_path} to {new_path}")
```

Another variant (*with* [pathlib](/questions/tagged/pathlib)) :

```
from pathlib import Path

directory = Path("C:/x/x/x/PDF")
df = pd.read_excel("New_name.xlsx")

for old_name, new_name in zip(df["Old_name"], df["New_name"]):
    old_path = directory / f"{old_name}.pdf"
    new_path = directory / f"{new_name}.pdf"

    if old_path.exists():
        old_path.rename(new_path)
        print(f"Renamed {old_path} to {new_path}")
```